# Sinatra application not working

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have built a simple rock paper scissor app in sinatra, but for some reason when I run `shotgun app.server.rb` and go to `localhost:9393`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.
Try this:
get / do
  Hello World
end
```

And in console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Here is my code: https://github.com/SammyAbukmeil/rps-challenge

To me this seemed as if the `server.rb` file isn't finding `views/index.erb`, so I have tried playing around with the lines of code that point to where views is found etc but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Does it work if you don’t use shotgun?

Comment: using ruby app/server.rb worked! Thanks matt

Answer (score 0):

Not using shotgun solved my problem, I used ruby app/server.rb

Comment: Try using `shotgun config.ru` if you still want to use Shotgun.

Comment: Awesome thanks Matt, will accept this answer in 2 days when I'm allowed to! :D